# Link to a front-end upload in email notification using the Sprout Forms plugin

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'm trying to add a link to a front-end upload in an email notification.  The docs say "To send notifications that include a direct link to your file, you can enable Template Overrides". I've done that, but all I can get is a link to a temporary file in cpresources/tempassets which doesn't exist any more.

I can't see how the code in the docs could be used in the email.html override file.

This is from the docs: (https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/examples/front-end-file-uploads)

```
{% set resume = object.resumeAssetFieldHandle.first() %}
Resume: {{ resume.getUrl() }}
```

But that doesn't work for me. Presumably resumeAssetFieldHandle is just an example field name but I don't know what the object is.

I have (after line 44)

```
{% if field.handle == 'uploadFile' %}
{{ value[0].getUrl() }}
{% endif %}
```

Which gives me the temp link.

Any pointers to how I can get the permanent link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was adding {slug} in the upload location. This worked for the final file but seems to trigger the behaviour where it links to the temp file.